# Determine paths through elements

Tags: java

I have a class Item, which uses a character as identifier.

```java
public class Item {

    private char identifier;
    private Set<Character> predecessors;
    private Set<Character> successors;

    // Constructor, getters and setters...

}
```

I would like to be able to retrieve the paths, represented by the `Path` class, which contains a simple ordered list of `Item` :

```java
public class Path {

    private List<Item> items;

    // Constructor, getters and setters 

}
```

To store and manage my items and paths, I use a dedicated class. It contains two `Set` containing each of these types. I can retrieve a task using its identifier.

```java
public class SimpleClass {

    private Set<Item> items;
    private Set<Path> paths;

    // Constructor, getters and setters

    public Optional<Item> getItemById(char identifier) {
        /// ....
    }

}
```

I would like to create a method to return a `Set` containing every `Path` but I can't do it. A little help would be welcome. A small example to illustrate my point:

[image: Graph example]

- D and E are the antecedents of G
- G is a successor of D and E
- A, B, D, G, J, K is a path
- A, C, F, H, J, K is a path

**Update / Note: I am looking to build the paths through the set of items**

Comment: Are you just asking how to transform your Set of Path into a List? Or ara you asking about building the Path from the Item classes?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am looking to build the paths through the set of items!

Comment: What i would do is to build a hashmap of keys Character and value list of Characters, to store all successors. build it by looping through your items, and also keep track of all items without antecedents, these are your starting points. Then from each starting point, create a path with the starting point, then find the successors. for each successor create a new path and add the item, then continue until you reach the end.

Comment: That's what I thought (except for the HashMap) but how to implement it in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty recursive algorithm. I just create the first map to speed up Item retrieval. See if it works, try to understand it and change it.

```
/**
 * Build all paths
 */
public void buildPaths() {
    Map<Character,Item> itemsByID=new HashMap<>();
    for (Item i:items) {
        itemsByID.put(i.getIdentifier(), i);
    }
    List<Item> starts=items.stream().filter(i->i.getPredecessors().isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (Item st:starts) {
        Path p=new Path();
        p.getItems().add(st);
        buildPath(p,itemsByID);
    }
}

/**
 * Build the next step of the given path
 * @param p
 * @param itemsByID
 */
private void buildPath(Path p,Map<Character,Item> itemsByID) {
    Item last=p.getItems().get(p.getItems().size()-1);
    Set<Character> successors=last.getSuccessors();
    // no successor, path is finished, add to collection
    if (successors.isEmpty()) {
        paths.add(p);
    // one successor continue on same path
    } else if (successors.size()==1){
        p.getItems().add(itemsByID.get(successors.iterator().next()));
        buildPath(p,itemsByID);
    } else {
        // multiple successors, create a new path for each branch
        for (Character c:successors) {
            Path p1=new Path();
            p1.getItems().addAll(p.getItems());
            p1.getItems().add(itemsByID.get(c));
            buildPath(p1, itemsByID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it when I get home. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Back with a little delay. The methods work perfectly. When you say it's a pretty dirty way to do it, is that it can be optimized?

Comment: It can probably be optimized but mainly it may need to handle loops in your graph, etc.